# Python output ordering

Tags: python, list, sorting, output

I have my code set up so it gets an API and outputs certain variables into a .txt file but i want it to order itself not through alphabetical order or anything but in priority order so if one of the variables is MVP it would be placed higher on the .txt as VIP and 80 would be higher than 20
this is an example of the .txt

```
b-88698@alt.com : thegiant20** [10]
e-b77b2@alt.com : Rancher** [1] [VIP]
5-c1eb6@alt.com : dogdad** [4] [VIP]
1-15a1f@alt.com : mb1mi** [0]
5-cd91b@alt.com : shalexa** [18] [MVP_PLUS]
```

but i want it ordered so it goes like this

```
5-cd91b@alt.com : shalexa** [18] [MVP_PLUS]
5-c1eb6@alt.com : dogdad** [4] [VIP]
e-b77b2@alt.com : Rancher** [1] [VIP]
b-88698@alt.com : thegiant20** [10]
1-15a1f@alt.com : mb1mi** [0]
```

Is there anything i could put in that could easily achieve this or not?

Comment: So first `MVP_PLUS>MVP>other` and in each look at the number between brackets ? What is 80 and 20 ?

Comment: it would go MVP_PLUS and 80 > MVP_PLUS and 20 > MVP > VIP_PLUS > VIP > 80 > 50 > 10 > 0 with the single number not being mvp or vip

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` method of a `list` has a `key` parameter where you can provide a function that will determine the sort order. This function has to find if it is an MVP or a VIP and it has to find the value in the square brackets.

```
import re

def main():
    lines = [
        'b-88698@alt.com : thegiant20** [10]',
        'e-b77b2@alt.com : Rancher** [1] [VIP]',
        '5-c1eb6@alt.com : dogdad** [4] [VIP]',
        '1-15a1f@alt.com : mb1mi** [0]',
        '5-cd91b@alt.com : shalexa** [18] [MVP_PLUS]',
    ]

def sortkey(value):
    is_mvp = '[MVP' in value
    is_vip = '[VIP' in value
    group = re.search(r'\[(\d+)\]', value)
    number = int(group[1])
    return is_mvp, is_vip, number

    lines.sort(key=sortkey, reverse=True)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comparison is done with a tuple. First value says if we have a MVP. The according value is `True` or `False` (or seen as an integer `1` or `0`). The second value is the same for a VIP. The last value is the number from the brackets converted to an integer.

Result

```
5-cd91b@alt.com : shalexa** [18] [MVP_PLUS]
5-c1eb6@alt.com : dogdad** [4] [VIP]
e-b77b2@alt.com : Rancher** [1] [VIP]
b-88698@alt.com : thegiant20** [10]
1-15a1f@alt.com : mb1mi** [0]
```

---

Add the following line in the `sortkey` function before you `return` and you'll see the value and the key that is generated for it and used for sorting.

```
    print(f'{value} -> key ({int(is_mvp)}, {int(is_vip)}, {number})')
```

Output

```
b-88698@alt.com : thegiant20** [10] -> key (0, 0, 10)
e-b77b2@alt.com : Rancher** [1] [VIP] -> key (0, 1, 1)
5-c1eb6@alt.com : dogdad** [4] [VIP] -> key (0, 1, 4)
1-15a1f@alt.com : mb1mi** [0] -> key (0, 0, 0)
5-cd91b@alt.com : shalexa** [18] [MVP_PLUS] -> key (1, 0, 18)
```

Comment: Could you change this so it takes in the output.txt file and orders the .txt then overwrites it?

Comment: If you don't know how to read and write files I suggest to look at the tutorial in the chapter "[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)". If you studied that and still have problems then please ask a new question. This grows far to broad for this question. Remember the rules you accepted when you registered here: This site is for questions and answers about one actual problem, not for full architectural solutions.